# How get the parent.document.referrer when cross domain?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Here is my problem:

1. page A in domain X
2. page B in domain Y
3. A have a iframe,and link to B

Now i can get the A's location in B by document.referrer，but my boss give me a new task:

> get the A's referer

First i tried:parent.document.referrer,it is as expected i encountered this error:"unsafe ... in cross domain".

So,guys,it's possible to get A'referer?How can i do it?

Thanks!

Comment: impossible because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You can only access the `REFERER` of the page that is reaching you. You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

You could bypass it though by providing the referer through a querystring variable.

E.g.

```
<iframe src="http://www.domainy.com?ref=Myreferer"></iframe>
```

Note though that a `REFERER` is not always set. Usually (but it varies in the different browsers) it is set when the page is reached by clicking a link, but there will be none when a user navigates directly to your webpage (enters URL in address bar) or by selecting one of his favorites.